# SQLITE in xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I get some example  but it's show more error

could share a link I can to follow for to create a database registration forms

> Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>
> Error     The "ResolveLibraryProjectImports" task failed unexpectedly.
>   System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load assembly 'Todo,
>   Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken='. Perhaps it doesn't
>   exist in the Mono for Android profile? File name: 'Todo.dll'    at
>   Java.Interop.Tools.Cecil.DirectoryAssemblyResolver.Resolve(AssemblyNameReference
>   reference, ReaderParameters parameters)    at
>   Java.Interop.Tools.Cecil.DirectoryAssemblyResolver.Resolve(String
>   fullName)    at
>   Xamarin.Android.Tasks.ResolveLibraryProjectImports.Extract(DirectoryAssemblyResolver
>   res, ICollection`1 jars, ICollection`1 resolvedResourceDirectories,
>   ICollection`1 resolvedAssetDirectories, ICollection`1
>   resolvedEnvironments)    at
>   Xamarin.Android.Tasks.ResolveLibraryProjectImports.Execute()    at
>   Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
>   at
>   Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.d__26.MoveNext() Todo.Android

Comment: This makes no sense what so ever...

Comment: I was see a video for to learn how I can create database but it isn't  to function, could you help

Comment: I'm beginner at xamarin forms

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/data-cloud/sync/azure-mobile-apps

Comment: post your code or we cant help you

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, the YouTubers omits/cuts some steps in the editing process. Try following the official documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/databases

Your error looks like your Todo project hasn't build successfully, that's why you are getting "Version=0.0.0.0" on the Exception's Stack.

Answer (score 0):

For the local database implementation use the following blog. It is very easy and a sample zip file is also available.
https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/mobile-local-databases-in-xamarin-forms-using-sqlite/